# Updating column value in a Table depends on other column value in another table SQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

there are two Table called OrderPayment and Ordersummaryinfo.
OrderPayment has a column Called  "orderNumber" and "paymentType".
where as OrderSummaryinfo has columns "orderNumber","ProductCd".

This OrderNumber is the primary key in OrderPayment table and is referring to OrderSummaryinfo.
OrderSummaryInfo.OrderNumber = OrderPayment.OrderNumber.

there are some paymentType's "CASH","REWARDS","GIFT" in OrderPayment Table.

There are some ProductCd's like "AUTO","NON_AUTO","AIR".

my Requirement is Wherever paymentType value is "CASH" i should change it to "REWARDS".
whenever i ran  "Update Orderpayment set paymentType='REWARDS' where Paymenttype="CASH" query it is doing for all of the Orders present in orderpayment table.

But i should the operation  only for AUTO Products.
SO how can i establish a link between these two tables . if possible any one can help me in this query .
Thanks

Comment: Not tested so run in a transaction . `UPDATE orderpayment set paymentype = 'REWARDS' from ordersummaryinfo where productcds = 'AUTO'  and  paymentype = 'CASH' and orderpayment.ordernumber = ordersummaryinfo.ordernumber`

Comment: Read [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) *Examples* section for more examples.

Comment: Just realized my example may not do what you want. If there are multiple items in `ordersummaryinfo` for a given `ordernumber` and they are a mix of `productcds`  then the `orderpayment.paymentype` will be set to `REWARDS` if just one of the items is of `productcd = 'AUTO'`. In other words the payment type is tied to the overall `orderpayment` not the individual items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I guess it should work now.

```
UPDATE OrderPayment 
SET paymentType = 'REWARDS'
FROM OrderSummaryinfo
WHERE OrderPayment.orderNumber = OrderSummaryinfo.orderNumber
AND OrderPayment.paymentType = 'CASH'
AND OrderSummaryinfo.ProductCd = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Hi Baktybek Baiserkeev @Baktybek Baiserkeev


it is giving an error when i ran saying "table name OrderPayment specified morethan once"

Comment: @Vijay fixed answer. Can you try it?